# Exporting an html for esp8266

Tags: esp8266, web-server, http

EDIT: Added "web page source" ("In the end", :D )

(Please, sorry if this question isn't in the right place, feel free to move it to that place)

Here I have a problem:

In my house I have a self-arming alarm (through hour(RTC) ) made by me, using an **Arduino Nano**, an **RTC1307** and some **sensors** (PIRs and magnetic). It works well, with its buttons, relays and LEDs to indicate.

All right, now I want to pass it to a **esp8266**, to be able to manage the alarm from the local network of my house using HTML and some  structures. I'm stuck in the construction part of the website, I mean: I already have the web page, at least opening the website from the browsers of the PC and my smartphone (**locally**), the question comes when I put the site inside the **esp8266**, It does not do what it has to do.

I have my webpage sectioned into 3 pieces using the HTML tags   and some *CSS* styles, to see the sections in the form of tabs but when I load them to the esp8266 it is as if I do not recognize the tabs, it does not let me click them.

I leave you the code here... please help:

```cpp
String getPage(){
  String page = "<!DOCTYPE HTML>";
  page += "<html>";
  page += "<head>";
  page += "<meta charset=\"utf-8\">";
  page += "<meta name = \"viewport\" content = \"width = device-width, initial-scale = 1.0\">";

  page += "<title>Alarma</title>";
  ///////////////
  ////ESTILOS////
  //////////////
  page += "<style>"; 
   page += "html { -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; }";
   page += "body { font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; line-height: 1.42857143; color: #333; background-color: #fff; }";

   page += ".well { min-height: 20px; padding: 19px; margin-bottom: 20px; background-color: #f5f5f5; border: 1px solid #e3e3e3; border-radius: 4px;}";
   page += "section { display: block; }";

   page += ".section { display: none;  padding: 20px 0 0;  border-top: 1px solid #ddd; }";

   page += "h1 { margin: .67em 0; font-size: 2em; font-family: inherit; font-weight: 500; line-height: 1.1; color: inherit;}";
   page += ".col-sm-2{ position: relative; min-height: 1px; padding-right: 15px; padding-left: 15px; }";
   page += "@media (min-width: 768px) { .col-sm-2 { float: left; width: 16.66666667%;} }";
   page += ".row { margin-right: -15px; margin-left: -15px;}";
   page += ".container { padding-right: 15px; padding-left: 15px; margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto;} ";
   page += ".container:before, .container:after,.row:before,.row:after{ display: table;  content: \" \";}";
   page += ".container:after,.row:after{ clear: both; }";
   page += "*, *:before, *:after { margin: 0;  padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }";
   page += ".input { display: none;}";
   page += "label { display: inline-block; margin: 0 0 -1px; padding: 15px 25px;font-weight: 600; text-align: center; color:  #079fc9; border: 1px solid transparent;}";
   page += "label:before { font-family: fontawesome; font-weight: normal; margin-right: 10px;}";
   page += "label[for*='1']:before { content: '\f1cb'; }";
   page += "label[for*='2']:before { content: '\f17d'; }";
   page += "label[for*='3']:before { content: '\f16b'; }";
   page += "label:hover { color: #888; cursor: pointer;}";
   page += "input:checked + label { color: #555; border: 1px solid #ddd; border-top: 2px solid #079fc9; border-bottom: 1px solid #fff; }";
   page += "#sensores:checked ~ #Sensores_activados, #hora_interna:checked ~ #Hora_interna, #hora_activacion:checked ~ #Hora_activacion  {  display: block;}";
   page += "@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {  label { padding: 15px; text-align: center; } }";

  page += "</style>";
  page += "</head>";

  ///////////////
  ////BODY  ////
  //////////////
  page += "<body>";
  page += "<section class=\"container\">";
  page += "<section class=\"well\">";
  page += "<h1>Página de configuración de la Alarma</h1>";
  page += "</section>";


  page += "<section class=\"well\">";
  page += "<input class=\"input\" id=\"sensores\" type=\"radio\" name=\"tabs\" checked>";
  page += "<label for=\"sensores\">Sensores activados</label>";

  page += "<input class=\"input\" id=\"hora_interna\" type=\"radio\" name=\"tabs\">";
  page += "<label for=\"hora_interna\">Hora Interna</label>";

  page += "<input  class=\"input\" id=\"hora_activacion\" type=\"radio\" name=\"tabs\">";
  page += "<label for=\"hora_activacion\">Hora de Auto-Armado/Desarmado</label>";

  page += "<section class=\"section\" id=\"Sensores_activados\">";
  //Formulario para sensores
  page += "<FORM action=\"/\" method=\"post\">";
  page += "Sensores activados<br>";
  page += "<p><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"M1\" id=\"M1\"";
  if (m1 == true){
    page += "checked";}
  page += "> M1<br>";
  page += "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"M2\" id=\"M2\"";
  if (m2 == true){
    page += "checked";}
  page += "> M2<br>";
  page += "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"M3\" id=\"M3\"";
  if (m3 == true){
    page += "checked";}
  page += "> M3<br>";
  page += "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"M4\" id=\"M4\"";
  if (m4 == true){
    page += "checked";}
  page += "> M4<br>";
  page += "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"PIR\" id=\"PIR\"";
  if (pir == true){
    page += "checked";}
  page += "> PIR<br>";
  page += "<INPUT class=\"btn\" type=\"submit\" value=\"Enviar\"> <INPUT class=\"btn\" type=\"reset\" value=\"Resetear\">";
  page += "</FORM>";
  page += "</section>";

  page += "<section class=\"section\" id=\"Hora_interna\">";
  //Formulario para PONER la hora
  page += "<FORM action=\"/\" method=\"post\">";
  page += "<p>Hora interna: <input type=\"time\" name=\"poner_hora\" id=\"poner_hora\" value=\"";
    if (hora_interna < 10){
      page += "0";
      }
  page += hora_interna;
  page += ":";
    if (minutos_interna < 10){
      page += "0";
      }
  page += minutos_interna;
  page += ":00\" size=\"5%\" max=\"23:59\" min=\"00:00\">";
  page += "<INPUT class=\"btn\" type=\"submit\" value=\"Enviar\"> <INPUT class=\"btn\" type=\"reset\" value=\"Resetear\">";
  page += "</FORM>";
  page += " </section>";

  page += "<section class=\"section\" id=\"Hora_activacion\">";
  //Formulario para hora de auto-armado
  page += "<FORM action=\"/\" method=\"post\">";
  page += "<section class=\"row\">";
  page += "<div class=\"col-sm-2\">Activación: <input type=\"time\" name=\"ontime\" id=\"ontime\" value=\"";
    if (hora_activacion < 10){
       page += "0";}
   hora_activacion;
   page += ":"; 
    if (minutos_activacion < 10){
       page += "0";}
   minutos_activacion;
   page += ":00 size=\"5%\" max=\"23:59\" min=\"00:00\"> </div>"; 
   page += "<div class=\"col-sm-2\">Desactivación: <input type=\"time\" name=\"offtime\" id=\"offtime\" value=\""; 
    if (hora_desactivacion < 10){
       page += "0";
      }
   hora_desactivacion;
   page += ":"; 
    if (minutos_desactivacion < 10){
      page += "0"; 
      }
   minutos_desactivacion;
   page += ":00 size=\"5%\" max=\"23:59\" min=\"00:00\"> </div></section><br>";
  page += "<INPUT class=\"btn\" type=\"submit\" value=\"Enviar\"> <INPUT class=\"btn\" type=\"reset\" value=\"Resetear\">";
  page += "</FORM>";
  page += "</section>";
  page += "</section>";
  page += "</section>";


  page += "</body>";
  page += "</html>";
  return page;
  }
```

What I see in my browser locally:
[image: What I see in my browser locally]

What I see in my browser when I load the page from the **esp8266**:
[image: What I see in my browser when I load the page from the **esp8266**]

I already check for the "*checked*" tag, in the  tag...

**The "web page source"** (apparently the browser put some "3D" before the quotes ("), any reason for that?)

```cpp
From: <Saved by Blink>
Subject: Alarma
Date: Wed, 5 Jun 2018 21:28:15 -0000
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/related;
    type="text/html";
    boundary="----MultipartBoundary--T8oNZJiKHmz7Uqtp7zBLZVTRAAqlj41o9li9KHDGiV----"

------MultipartBoundary--T8oNZJiKHmz7Uqtp7zBLZVTRAAqlj41o9li9KHDGiV----
Content-Type: text/html
Content-ID: <frame-2-73f97ce7-1d30-423c-a8b1-c57104e83c66@mhtml.blink>
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Content-Location: http://192.168.43.5/

<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta http-equiv=3D"Content-Type" content=3D"tex=
t/html; charset=3DUTF-8"><meta name=3D"viewport" content=3D"width =3D devic=
e-width, initial-scale =3D 1.0"><title>Alarma</title><style>html { -webkit-=
text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; }body { font-family: He=
lvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; line-height: 1=
.42857143; color: #333; background-color: #fff; }.well { min-height: 20px; =
padding: 19px; margin-bottom: 20px; background-color: #f5f5f5; border: 1px =
solid #e3e3e3; border-radius: 4px;}section { display: block; }.section { di=
splay: none;  padding: 20px 0 0;  border-top: 1px solid #ddd; }h1 { margin:=
 .67em 0; font-size: 2em; font-family: inherit; font-weight: 500; line-heig=
ht: 1.1; color: inherit;}.col-sm-2{ position: relative; min-height: 1px; pa=
dding-right: 15px; padding-left: 15px; }@media (min-width: 768px) { .col-sm=
-2 { float: left; width: 16.66666667%;} }.row { margin-right: -15px; margin=
-left: -15px;}.container { padding-right: 15px; padding-left: 15px; margin-=
right: auto; margin-left: auto;} .container:before, .container:after,.row:b=
efore,.row:after{ display: table;  content: " ";}.container:after,.row:afte=
r{ clear: both; }*, *:before, *:after { margin: 0;  padding: 0; box-sizing:=
 border-box; }.input { display: none;}label { display: inline-block; margin=
: 0 0 -1px; padding: 15px 25px;font-weight: 600; text-align: center; color:=
  #079fc9; border: 1px solid transparent;}label:before { font-family: fonta=
wesome; font-weight: normal; margin-right: 10px;}label[for*=3D'1']:before {=
 content: '=0C1cb'; }label[for*=3D'2']:before { content: '=0C17d'; }label[f=
or*=3D'3']:before { content: '=0C16b'; }label:hover { color: #888; cursor: =
pointer;}input:checked + label { color: #555; border: 1px solid #ddd; borde=
r-top: 2px solid #079fc9; border-bottom: 1px solid #fff; }#sensores:checked=
 ~ #Sensores_activados, #hora_interna:checked ~ #Hora_interna, #hora_activa=
cion:checked ~ #Hora_activacion  {  display: block;}@media screen and (max-=
width: 400px) {  label { padding: 15px; text-align: center; } }</style></he=
ad><body><section class=3D"container"><section class=3D"well"><h1>P=C3=A1gi=
na de configuraci=C3=B3n de la Alarma</h1></section><section class=3D"well"=
><input class=3D"input" id=3D"sensores" type=3D"radio" name=3D"tabs" checke=
d=3D""><label for=3D"sensores">Sensores activados</label><input class=3D"in=
put" id=3D"hora_interna" type=3D"radio" name=3D"tabs"><label for=3D"hora_in=
terna">Hora Interna</label><input class=3D"input" id=3D"hora_activacion" ty=
pe=3D"radio" name=3D"tabs"><label for=3D"hora_activacion">Hora de Auto-Arma=
do/Desarmado</label><section class=3D"section" id=3D"Sensores_activados"><f=
orm action=3D"http://192.168.43.5/" method=3D"post">Sensores activados<br><=
p><input type=3D"checkbox" name=3D"M1" id=3D"M1" checked=3D""> M1<br><input=
 type=3D"checkbox" name=3D"M2" id=3D"M2" checked=3D""> M2<br><input type=3D=
"checkbox" name=3D"M3" id=3D"M3" checked=3D""> M3<br><input type=3D"checkbo=
x" name=3D"M4" id=3D"M4" checked=3D""> M4<br><input type=3D"checkbox" name=
=3D"PIR" id=3D"PIR" checked=3D""> PIR<br><input class=3D"btn" type=3D"submi=
t" value=3D"Enviar"> <input class=3D"btn" type=3D"reset" value=3D"Resetear"=
></p></form></section><section class=3D"section" id=3D"Hora_interna"><form =
action=3D"http://192.168.43.5/" method=3D"post"><p>Hora interna: <input typ=
e=3D"time" name=3D"poner_hora" id=3D"poner_hora" value=3D"10:40" size=3D"5%=
" max=3D"23:59" min=3D"00:00"><input class=3D"btn" type=3D"submit" value=3D=
"Enviar"> <input class=3D"btn" type=3D"reset" value=3D"Resetear"></p></form=
> </section><section class=3D"section" id=3D"Hora_activacion"><form action=
=3D"http://192.168.43.5/" method=3D"post"><section class=3D"row"><div class=
=3D"col-sm-2">Activaci=C3=B3n: <input type=3D"time" name=3D"ontime" id=3D"o=
ntime" value=3D"10:40" size=3D"5%" max=3D"23:59" min=3D"00:00"> </div><div =
class=3D"col-sm-2">Desactivaci=C3=B3n: <input type=3D"time" name=3D"offtime=
" id=3D"offtime" value=3D"=08:40&quot;" size=3D"5%" max=3D"23:59" min=3D"00=
:00"> </div></section><br><input class=3D"btn" type=3D"submit" value=3D"Env=
iar"> <input class=3D"btn" type=3D"reset" value=3D"Resetear"></form></secti=
on></section></section></body></html>
------MultipartBoundary--T8oNZJiKHmz7Uqtp7zBLZVTRAAqlj41o9li9KHDGiV------
```

I´ll add my entire code:

```cpp
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>

//Definir el led
#define LED 2 

//Variables de apoyo
bool m1 = true;
bool m2 = true;
bool m3 = true;
bool m4 = true;
bool pir = true;



//SSID and Password of your WiFi router
const char* ssid = "asd";
const char* password = "12345678";

ESP8266WebServer server(80);


//////////////////////////////////////////////
//                 Index                    //
/////////////////////////////////////////////
String getPage(){
  String page = "<!DOCTYPE HTML>";
  page += "<html>";
  page += "<head>";
  page += "<meta charset=\"utf-8\">";
  page += "<meta name = \"viewport\" content = \"width = device-width, initial-scale = 1.0\">";

  page += "<title>Alarma</title>";
  ///////////////
  ////ESTILOS////
  //////////////
  page += "<style>"; 
   page += "html { -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; }";
   page += "body { font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; line-height: 1.42857143; color: #333; background-color: #fff; }";

   page += ".well { min-height: 20px; padding: 19px; margin-bottom: 20px; background-color: #f5f5f5; border: 1px solid #e3e3e3; border-radius: 4px;}";
   page += "section { display: block; }";

   page += ".section { display: none;  padding: 20px 0 0;  border-top: 1px solid #ddd; }";

   page += "h1 { margin: .67em 0; font-size: 2em; font-family: inherit; font-weight: 500; line-height: 1.1; color: inherit;}";
   page += ".col-sm-2{ position: relative; min-height: 1px; padding-right: 15px; padding-left: 15px; }";
   page += "@media (min-width: 768px) { .col-sm-2 { float: left; width: 16.66666667%;} }";
   page += ".row { margin-right: -15px; margin-left: -15px;}";
   page += ".container { padding-right: 15px; padding-left: 15px; margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto;} ";
   page += ".container:before, .container:after,.row:before,.row:after{ display: table;  content: \" \";}";
   page += ".container:after,.row:after{ clear: both; }";
   page += "*, *:before, *:after { margin: 0;  padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }";
   page += ".input { display: none;}";
   page += "label { display: inline-block; margin: 0 0 -1px; padding: 15px 25px;font-weight: 600; text-align: center; color:  #079fc9; border: 1px solid transparent;}";
   page += "label:before { font-family: fontawesome; font-weight: normal; margin-right: 10px;}";
   page += "label[for*='1']:before { content: '\f1cb'; }";
   page += "label[for*='2']:before { content: '\f17d'; }";
   page += "label[for*='3']:before { content: '\f16b'; }";
   page += "label:hover { color: #888; cursor: pointer;}";
   page += "input:checked + label { color: #555; border: 1px solid #ddd; border-top: 2px solid #079fc9; border-bottom: 1px solid #fff; }";
   page += "#sensores:checked ~ #Sensores_activados, #hora_interna:checked ~ #Hora_interna, #hora_activacion:checked ~ #Hora_activacion  {  display: block;}";
   page += "@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {  label { padding: 15px; text-align: center; } }";

  page += "</style>";
  page += "</head>";

  ///////////////
  ////BODY  ////
  //////////////
  page += "<body>";
  page += "<section class=\"container\">";
  page += "<section class=\"well\">";
  page += "<h1>Página de configuración de la Alarma</h1>";
  page += "</section>";


  page += "<section class=\"well\">";
  page += "<input class=\"input\" id=\"sensores\" type=\"radio\" name=\"tabs\" checked>";
  page += "<label for=\"sensores\">Sensores activados</label>";

  page += "<input class=\"input\" id=\"hora_interna\" type=\"radio\" name=\"tabs\">";
  page += "<label for=\"hora_interna\">Hora Interna</label>";

  page += "<input  class=\"input\" id=\"hora_activacion\" type=\"radio\" name=\"tabs\">";
  page += "<label for=\"hora_activacion\">Hora de Auto-Armado/Desarmado</label>";

  page += "<section class=\"section\" id=\"Sensores_activados\">";
  //Formulario para sensores
  page += "<FORM action=\"/\" method=\"post\">";
  page += "Sensores activados<br>";
  page += "<p><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"M1\" id=\"M1\"";
  if (m1 == true){
    page += "checked";}
  page += "> M1<br>";
  page += "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"M2\" id=\"M2\"";
  if (m2 == true){
    page += "checked";}
  page += "> M2<br>";
  page += "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"M3\" id=\"M3\"";
  if (m3 == true){
    page += "checked";}
  page += "> M3<br>";
  page += "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"M4\" id=\"M4\"";
  if (m4 == true){
    page += "checked";}
  page += "> M4<br>";
  page += "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"PIR\" id=\"PIR\"";
  if (pir == true){
    page += "checked";}
  page += "> PIR<br>";
  page += "<INPUT class=\"btn\" type=\"submit\" value=\"Enviar\"> <INPUT class=\"btn\" type=\"reset\" value=\"Resetear\">";
  page += "</FORM>";
  page += "</section>";

  page += "<section class=\"section\" id=\"Hora_interna\">";
  //Formulario para PONER la hora
  page += "<FORM action=\"/\" method=\"post\">";
  page += "<p>Hora interna: <input type=\"time\" name=\"poner_hora\" id=\"poner_hora\" value=\"";
    if (hora_interna < 10){
      page += "0";
      }
  page += hora_interna;
  page += ":";
    if (minutos_interna < 10){
      page += "0";
      }
  page += minutos_interna;
  page += ":00\" size=\"5%\" max=\"23:59\" min=\"00:00\">";
  page += "<INPUT class=\"btn\" type=\"submit\" value=\"Enviar\"> <INPUT class=\"btn\" type=\"reset\" value=\"Resetear\">";
  page += "</FORM>";
  page += " </section>";

  page += "<section class=\"section\" id=\"Hora_activacion\">";
  //Formulario para hora de auto-armado
  page += "<FORM action=\"/\" method=\"post\">";
  page += "<section class=\"row\">";
  page += "<div class=\"col-sm-2\">Activación: <input type=\"time\" name=\"ontime\" id=\"ontime\" value=\"";
    if (hora_activacion < 10){
       page += "0";}
   hora_activacion;
   page += ":"; 
    if (minutos_activacion < 10){
       page += "0";}
   minutos_activacion;
   page += ":00 size=\"5%\" max=\"23:59\" min=\"00:00\"> </div>"; 
   page += "<div class=\"col-sm-2\">Desactivación: <input type=\"time\" name=\"offtime\" id=\"offtime\" value=\""; 
    if (hora_desactivacion < 10){
       page += "0";
      }
   hora_desactivacion;
   page += ":"; 
    if (minutos_desactivacion < 10){
      page += "0"; 
      }
   minutos_desactivacion;
   page += ":00 size=\"5%\" max=\"23:59\" min=\"00:00\"> </div></section><br>";
  page += "<INPUT class=\"btn\" type=\"submit\" value=\"Enviar\"> <INPUT class=\"btn\" type=\"reset\" value=\"Resetear\">";
  page += "</FORM>";
  page += "</section>";
  page += "</section>";
  page += "</section>";


  page += "</body>";
  page += "</html>";
  return page;
  }



//////////////////////////////////////////////
//          REDIRECCIONAMIENTO             //
/////////////////////////////////////////////
void handleNotFound(){
  server.sendHeader("Location", "/",true);   //Redirect to our html web page  
  server.send(302, "text/plane","");
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////
//      handleSubmit                        //
/////////////////////////////////////////////
void handleSubmit(){
  //Atencion a sensores
  if (server.arg("M1") == "on"){
      m1 = !m1;
      Serial.println("Se activo el sensor M1");
      }
  if (server.arg("M2") == "on"){
      m2 = !m2;
      Serial.println("Se activo el sensor M2");
      }
  if (server.arg("M3") == "on"){
      m3 = !m3;
      Serial.println("Se activo el sensor M3");
      }
  if (server.arg("M4") == "on"){
      m4 = !m4;
      Serial.println("Se activo el sensor M4");
      }
  if (server.arg("PIR") == "on"){
      pir = !pir;
      Serial.println("Se activo el sensor PIR");
    }

  //Atencion a establecimiento de la hora
//  if (server.hasArg("poner_hora")){
//    Serial.println(server.arg("poner_hora"));
//    }

  server.send(200, "text/plain", getPage());       //Response to the HTTP request

}  


//////////////////////////////////////////////
//      handleRoot                          //
/////////////////////////////////////////////
void handleRoot() {
 Serial.println("You called root page");

  if (!server.args() ) {
    Serial.println("Hay algun argumento valido");
    handleSubmit();
    } else {
      server.send(200, "text/html", getPage());  
      }
}



//////////////////////////////////////////////
//                SETUP                     //
/////////////////////////////////////////////

void setup() {
  delay(1000);
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("Sistema iniciando");

  //Initialize AP Mode
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);     //Connect to your WiFi router
  Serial.println("");

  //Onboard LED port Direction output
  pinMode(LED,OUTPUT); 
  //Power on LED state off
  digitalWrite(LED,HIGH);

  // Wait for connection
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }

  server.on("/", handleRoot);
  server.onNotFound(handleNotFound);

  server.begin();
  Serial.print("Conectate a ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}


//////////////////////////////////////////////
//                LOOP                      //
///////////////////////////////////////////// 
void loop() {
  server.handleClient();         //Handling of incoming requests
}
```

Comment: But have you checked the page source?

Comment: Yeap, at first I see some garbage (I also checked other webpage to make sure), something like "ContentType" and stuff like that...

Comment: please post the "web page source" from the esp8288

Comment: Don't use Strings. Save the file in the SPIFFS. Make it static, and fetch dynamic data using JavaScript.

Comment: What is SPIFFS? Let me do some research

Comment: Does the webserver on the ESP support all the features you are trying to use?  0x3D is the ASCII code for =, is there some encoding issue with you code?

Comment: @CodeGorilla I really don't know. How can I know if my ESP (**Wemos D1 R1**) has support for these CSS code? And why I see the *3D* ASCII code? I have reviewed the entire code once and once again, with the same result. Rigth now I continue working without the CSS code... pure HTML, but is ugly!!!

Comment: It looks like you page source that is being rendered is email content. The 3D is from the email encoding and I have seen that on Gmail a lot(presumably Gmail parses the = out). What is the way in which you are delivering the webpage from the ESP to an end user? As a reference: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable

Comment: Hi @RSM, I don't understand your question: what do you mean when you say: "What is the way in which you are delivering the webpage from the ESP to an end user?"? And why the navigator from my phone can even think that the content of the webpage is some kind of email?
(Sorry for the late answer, I don't have a free internet access)

Comment: @k.Cyborg The web page source you pasted in has the headers of an email. So at some point, the web page is being made into an email. What why are you using to access the webpage from your phone. Are you using a library to show the page.    Or did you email a copy of the webpage source to be able to past it on the website.  _Would you be able to post your code you running ?_

Comment: HI @RSM, the web page "source" that I pasted is what the navigator (Chrome) from my cell-phone (Xioami RedMi Note4) see, the way I found to "see" what I pasted here (the "source") is downloading the page from my phone and opening it with SublimeText(3.x). I post me entire code, but I'm no using any specific library, just the standart ESP8266WebServer, ESP8266WiFi and the WiFiClient... all of them (and the code, obviosuly) is using the Arduino IDE 1.8.5... any more information that you need? I appreciate any help!

Comment: @k.Cyborg Sorry for not replying earlier. Can you try change all the server.send() to use "text/html" and see if that shows anything as you have set it to plain text so the browser might not be interpreting it properly